# Margin left and right not the same

Tags: html, css

In the code snippet below you can see that the input field and the button have more margin on the left than on the right. They do have a margin on all sides of 10px.
Why is the margin not equal on both sides and how can I fix this?

Many thanks in advance.
Kind regards

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font: verdana;
}
html, body {
  font-family: consolas;
  color: #707070 ;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

#login_form {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/*CSS responsive*/
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
}

.button {
  background-color: #003366;
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: consolas;
  color: #707070;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Index
  </title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
      <div class="col-6" id="login_form">
        <form action="" method="" name="">
          E-mail:<br />
          <input type="text" name="login_email" value="" class="input" /><br />
          Password:<br />
          <input type="password" name="login_password" value="" class="input"/><br />
          <button class="button">Log in</button>
        </form>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was: your input had 100%, width more 20px padding and 20px margin. This results in more than 100%. That's why it was bigger on the right side.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font: verdana;
}
html, body {
  font-family: consolas;
  color: #707070 ;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

#login_form {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/*CSS responsive*/
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
}

.input-wrapper,
.button-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
}
.button {
  background-color: #003366;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: consolas;
  color: #707070;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Index
  </title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
      <div class="col-6" id="login_form">
        <form action="" method="" name="">
          E-mail:
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="login_email" value="" class="input" />
          </div>
          Password:
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="password" name="login_password" value="" class="input"/>
          </div>
          <div class="button-wrapper">
            <button class="button">Log in</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I see that you removed the margin and created a wrapper around the input-div to work with paddings. Can you explain why is doesn't work with margin?

Comment: You could use margin in that wrapper instead of padding. Anyway, it must be always in a wrapper. The problem is you can't mix 100% of width with margins, or it always result in more than 100%.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `margin` is not included in the border-box sizing model. It's separate. So the elements are 100% `width`, plus the 10px of `margin` on each side. It's not actually that there's more spacing on the left, it's just that the right `margin` is off the visible page. Just remove the `margin` from both elements and you should be set. See the snippet below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font: verdana;
}

html, body {
  font-family: consolas;
  color: #707070 ;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

#login_form {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/*CSS responsive*/
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.button {
  background-color: #003366;
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: consolas;
  color: #707070;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Index
  </title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
      <div class="col-6" id="login_form">
        <form action="" method="" name="">
          E-mail:<br />
          <input type="text" name="login_email" value="" class="input" /><br />
          Password:<br />
          <input type="password" name="login_password" value="" class="input"/><br />
          <button class="button">Log in</button>
        </form>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I didn't knew the margin is not included in the box sizing model.